# Use vue page template syntax {{}} to call asynchronous functions to complete page rendering

Tags: html, vue.js

Using Vue page template syntax {{}} to call asynchronous functions to complete page rendering,
you can take a value inside the function.
There is a problem with the page display.

A normal method function returns information normally

```
  get_count(id) { 
    return id;
  },
```

A problem occurred when using the asynchronous function method

```
  async get_count(id) { 
    return await get('/count',{"id":id});
  },
```

Page shows

Object Promise

Is there something wrong with my template syntax {{get_count}} or does it need a special tag?

Comment: Edit your post not awat but await

Answer (score 0):

**The Bottom line is: methods are not reactive, only data is reactive in Vue.**

Possible soultion of your problem:

1.Create a data property:

```
data() {
    return {
      count: null
    };
  }
```

2.Create a method to fetch your data. You don't need async/await syntacsis, also you need some tool for making a request, like axios:

```
methods: {
    setCount() {
        axios.get('/count',{"id":id})
        .then(res => (this.count = res.data));
    }
}
```

3.Create a computed property to watch your data:

```
   getCount() {
      return this.count ? this.count : "";
    }
```

4.Display your computed property in the template:

```
{{ getCount }}
```

Comment: I've tried this method which is not very friendly for multiple template calls and it gives the same result for the same page
I want him to be unique

Comment: then you can bind your fetch method to some event and call it on every event. Then computed property would be updating.